# How to make the text in outputs function print letter by letter in Python3?

Tags: python

This is the script I am working on and I am trying to make it so that the text in the outputs function prints letter by letter yet, I am having a hard time doing so. I have experimented with the `"time.sleep"` module but to no avail.

It is a personal project in which the user sees the menu, selects an option and then that option presents information. I am trying to get the output of the selection print letter by letter.

```
import colorama
import pyfiglet
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

colorama.init()

# create a list of outputs
outputs = [
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n A white hat hacker is a computer security expert who uses their skills to identify and remediate security vulnerabilities in computer systems, networks, and applications. They are also referred to as ethical hackers or penetration testers.\n\n White hat hackers use the same methods and tools as malicious hackers (also known as \"black hat hackers\"), but with the express permission of the system or network owner, and with the goal of improving security. White hat hackers may be employed by companies to test the security of their own systems, or they may work independently as consultants or contractors.White hat hackers use a variety of techniques to identify and exploit vulnerabilities, including network scanning, vulnerability scanning, penetration testing, and social engineering. They also use methods to ensure that any vulnerabilities they find are thoroughly documented and reported to the appropriate parties, and that recommendations for remediation are clear and actionable. \n\n White hat hackers must have a deep understanding of computer systems, networks, and software, as well as a solid understanding of security best practices and industry standards. They should also have strong problem-solving and analytical skills, as well as good communication skills, as their role often requires working with other security professionals, as well as with non-technical stakeholders.\n\n The role of white hat hackers is becoming increasingly important as the number and sophistication of cyber attacks continue to rise. They help organizations to identify and remediate vulnerabilities before they can be exploited by malicious actors.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Gray hat hackers are a hybrid of white hat and black hat hackers. They may act with malicious intent, but their actions are not necessarily illegal. They may identify vulnerabilities in systems and networks but instead of reporting it to the owners, they may exploit it for personal gain or to publicize the vulnerability.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n A black hat hacker historically has been used to describe one who has malicious intent -- such as theft of information, fraud or disrupting systems -- but increasingly, more specific terms are being used to describe those people. \n\nA hacker may exploit security vulnerabilities for monetary gain; steal or destroy private data; or alter, disrupt or shut down websites and networks.\n\n.The hacker may also sell these exploits to other criminal organizations. The term black hat has been used to differentiate criminal hackers from white hat and gray hat hackers. These categories were inspired by early Western movies, where the heroes could be identified by the white hats they wore and the villains by their black hats.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Derived from combining the words ‘Hack’ and ‘Activism’, hacktivism is the act of hacking, or breaking into a computer system, for politically or socially motivated purposes. The individual who performs an act of hacktivism is said to be a hacktivist. The hacktivist who does such acts, such as defacing an organization’s website or leaking that organization’s information, aims to send a message through their activities and gain visibility for a cause they are promoting.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n The Nation State Actor has a ‘Licence to Hack’. They work for a government to disrupt or compromise target governments, organisations or individuals to gain access to valuable data or intelligence, and can create incidents that have international significance. \n\nThey might be part of a semi-hidden ‘cyber army’ or ‘hackers for hire’ for companies that are aligned to the aims of a government or dictatorship. The Nation State Actor knows exactly what they’re getting into, and knows full well that the mayhem they’re spreading overseas is tacitly supported by their state. \n\nWhat are their motivations?\nFinancial gain: Such countries as North Korea also manage to generate cash from such attacks. \n\nDemonstrations of national pride: Such attacks are often driven by the attacking country’s willingness to display power and the ability to incur large-scale damage. \n\nCyberwarfare activities: Nation-state actors are the main participants of cyberwars, which can accompany physical conflicts or take place without the presence of physical warfare. Usually, such threats affect some critical infrastructure to cripple a country's economic, military, or political sectors. For example, nation-state threat actors can steal military data or hack railway systems. \n\nEspionage: Nation-state attacks help to obtain confidential data for cyberattackers.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Lacking programming knowledge or skill, script kiddies use code and tools created by others to launch cyber attacks and gain unauthorised access to data. \n\nUsually, script kiddies learn basic hacking techniques from online sources such as YouTube, or utilise free tools aimed at budding penetration testers. Combined with pre-existing scripts and software, script kiddies are able to perform attacks on companies and individuals. Often, these script kiddies may not understand the mechanics and theory behind what they are doing, so are not classed as hackers specifically. \n\nWhere organised crime gangs operate cyber attacks, they may make use of script kiddies. Although they may be hired by large criminal groups, script kiddies can, and do, launch attacks of their own, too. If not working for a larger criminal gang, script kiddies may be indiscriminate in their targets. The unsophisticated nature of their knowledge means that they may simply try to attack any computer that they can, working opportunistically. ",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Sweet!"
]

def display_menu():
    print(colorama.Fore.BLUE + Style.BRIGHT)
    print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("Hacker Classifications", font="big"))
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Please Choose which hacker you would like to learn about from the list below!")
    print()
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "1. White Hat Hackers")
    print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + "2. Gray Hat Hackers")
    print(colorama.Fore.RED + "3. Black Hat Hackers")
    print(colorama.Fore.CYAN + "4. Hacktivists")
    print(colorama.Fore.BLUE + "5. Nation States")
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "6. Script Kiddies")
    try:
        selection = int(input(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Please enter your selection: ")) - 1
        print(outputs[selection])
        for i in range(10):  # modified loop to ask for another option 10 times
            another_option = input(colorama.Fore.BLUE + "Would you like to see another option? (Yes/No) ")
            if another_option.lower() == "no" or another_option.lower() == "n":
                break
            which_option = input(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Which option would you like to see? ")
            try:
                which_option = int(which_option) - 1  # convert input to integer and subtract 1 to get the index
                print(outputs[which_option])
            except ValueError:
                print(colorama.Fore.RED + "Invalid selection. Please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print(colorama.Fore.RED + "Invalid selection. Please try again.")

    while True:
        go_back = input(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Would you like to go back to the menu? (Yes/No) ")
        if go_back.lower() == "no" or go_back.lower() == "n":
            print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + "Thanks for learning with us today!")
            break
        elif go_back.lower() == "yes" or go_back.lower() == "y":
            display_menu()  # call the function recursively to display the menu again
            break

display_menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import colorama
import pyfiglet
import sys
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()

# create a list of outputs
outputs = [
    colorama.Fore.WHITE +"\n A white hat hacker is a computer security expert who uses their skills to identify and remediate security vulnerabilities in computer systems, networks, and applications. They are also referred to as ethical hackers or penetration testers.\n\n White hat hackers use the same methods and tools as malicious hackers (also known as \"black hat hackers\"), but with the express permission of the system or network owner, and with the goal of improving security. White hat hackers may be employed by companies to test the security of their own systems, or they may work independently as consultants or contractors.White hat hackers use a variety of techniques to identify and exploit vulnerabilities, including network scanning, vulnerability scanning, penetration testing, and social engineering. They also use methods to ensure that any vulnerabilities they find are thoroughly documented and reported to the appropriate parties, and that recommendations for remediation are clear and actionable. \n\n White hat hackers must have a deep understanding of computer systems, networks, and software, as well as a solid understanding of security best practices and industry standards. They should also have strong problem-solving and analytical skills, as well as good communication skills, as their role often requires working with other security professionals, as well as with non-technical stakeholders.\n\n The role of white hat hackers is becoming increasingly important as the number and sophistication of cyber attacks continue to rise. They help organizations to identify and remediate vulnerabilities before they can be exploited by malicious actors.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Gray hat hackers are a hybrid of white hat and black hat hackers. They may act with malicious intent, but their actions are not necessarily illegal. They may identify vulnerabilities in systems and networks but instead of reporting it to the owners, they may exploit it for personal gain or to publicize the vulnerability.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n A black hat hacker historically has been used to describe one who has malicious intent -- such as theft of information, fraud or disrupting systems -- but increasingly, more specific terms are being used to describe those people. \n\nA hacker may exploit security vulnerabilities for monetary gain; steal or destroy private data; or alter, disrupt or shut down websites and networks.\n\n.The hacker may also sell these exploits to other criminal organizations. The term black hat has been used to differentiate criminal hackers from white hat and gray hat hackers. These categories were inspired by early Western movies, where the heroes could be identified by the white hats they wore and the villains by their black hats.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Derived from combining the words ‘Hack’ and ‘Activism’, hacktivism is the act of hacking, or breaking into a computer system, for politically or socially motivated purposes. The individual who performs an act of hacktivism is said to be a hacktivist. The hacktivist who does such acts, such as defacing an organization’s website or leaking that organization’s information, aims to send a message through their activities and gain visibility for a cause they are promoting.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n The Nation State Actor has a ‘Licence to Hack’. They work for a government to disrupt or compromise target governments, organisations or individuals to gain access to valuable data or intelligence, and can create incidents that have international significance. \n\nThey might be part of a semi-hidden ‘cyber army’ or ‘hackers for hire’ for companies that are aligned to the aims of a government or dictatorship. The Nation State Actor knows exactly what they’re getting into, and knows full well that the mayhem they’re spreading overseas is tacitly supported by their state. \n\nWhat are their motivations?\nFinancial gain: Such countries as North Korea also manage to generate cash from such attacks. \n\nDemonstrations of national pride: Such attacks are often driven by the attacking country’s willingness to display power and the ability to incur large-scale damage. \n\nCyberwarfare activities: Nation-state actors are the main participants of cyberwars, which can accompany physical conflicts or take place without the presence of physical warfare. Usually, such threats affect some critical infrastructure to cripple a country's economic, military, or political sectors. For example, nation-state threat actors can steal military data or hack railway systems. \n\nEspionage: Nation-state attacks help to obtain confidential data for cyberattackers.",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Lacking programming knowledge or skill, script kiddies use code and tools created by others to launch cyber attacks and gain unauthorised access to data. \n\nUsually, script kiddies learn basic hacking techniques from online sources such as YouTube, or utilise free tools aimed at budding penetration testers. Combined with pre-existing scripts and software, script kiddies are able to perform attacks on companies and individuals. Often, these script kiddies may not understand the mechanics and theory behind what they are doing, so are not classed as hackers specifically. \n\nWhere organised crime gangs operate cyber attacks, they may make use of script kiddies. Although they may be hired by large criminal groups, script kiddies can, and do, launch attacks of their own, too. If not working for a larger criminal gang, script kiddies may be indiscriminate in their targets. The unsophisticated nature of their knowledge means that they may simply try to attack any computer that they can, working opportunistically. ",
    colorama.Fore.WHITE + "\n Sweet!"
]

def display_menu():
    print(colorama.Fore.BLUE + Style.BRIGHT)
    print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("Hacker Classifications", font="big"))
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Please Choose which hacker you would like to learn about from the list below!")
    print()
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "1. White Hat Hackers")
    print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + "2. Gray Hat Hackers")
    print(colorama.Fore.RED + "3. Black Hat Hackers")
    print(colorama.Fore.CYAN + "4. Hacktivists")
    print(colorama.Fore.BLUE + "5. Nation States")
    print(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "6. Script Kiddies")
    try:
        selection = int(input(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Please enter your selection: ")) - 1
        for letter in outputs[selection]:
            print(letter, end="")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            import time
            time.sleep(0.05)
        print()
        for i in range(10):
            another_option = input(colorama.Fore.BLUE + "Would you like to see another option? (Yes/No) ")
            if another_option.lower() == "no" or another_option.lower() == "n":
                break
            which_option = input(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Which option would you like to see? ")
            try:
                which_option = int(which_option) - 1
                for letter in outputs[which_option]:
                    print(letter, end="")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(0.05)
                print()
            except ValueError:
                print(colorama.Fore.RED + "Invalid selection. Please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print(colorama.Fore.RED + "Invalid selection. Please try again.")

    while True:
        go_back = input(colorama.Fore.WHITE + "Would you like to go back to the menu? (Yes/No) ")
        if go_back.lower() == "no" or go_back.lower() == "n":
            print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + "Thanks for learning with us today!")
            break
        elif go_back.lower() == "yes" or go_back.lower() == "y":
            display_menu()  # call the function recursively to display the menu again
            break

display_menu()
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, it is always better to include some details of how and why your answer works along with the code snippet.

Comment: Thank you all! Haven’t logged in, in a while! 
My apologies for the bad etiquete leaving the answer, unanswered for so long!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to iterate through each character in the string, and use the time.sleep() function to pause the program for a short period of time before printing the next character

Example:

```py
import time

output = "your text"

for char in output:
    print(char, end="")
    time.sleep(0.05) # The program waiting 0.05 seconds before printing the next character
```

Comment: +1! Thank you for your advice! I managed to figure it out in the end and used the sys module in conjunction with the time module to achieve what I needed. I have posted the answer in these comments!

Thanks again and stay awesome!